# How to select second page as initial page with jQuery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using jQuery datatable.By default it is  showing first page as initial page .But i want to show the second page as default page.When i am using YUI data table .In that i have option like `initialPage`.Is there any possibility in jQuery datatable to select second page as initial page.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't an option in default options object. However you can call **fnPageChange** function on datatable to set the pagenumber.

```
var table = $('#data_table').dataTable();
table.fnPageChange(2,true);
```

Where 2 is the page number and the second parameter asks datatable to redraw.

https://datatables.net/ref#fnPageChange

Comment: Thank u so much.I wasted 3 hrs on this

Answer (score 19):

With version 1.10 of `DataTables` there is a `displayStart` option that will allow you to set the default page.

Note that the `displayStart` value is a zero based count of records, not pages. If you have 10 records per page, `displayStart: 10` will show page 2

```
$('#my-datatable').DataTable( {
  'displayStart': 10
} );
```

https://datatables.net/reference/option/displayStart

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and the source was using legacy version of datatable. I could fix it by setting "iDisplayStart".