# Custom paging with array of JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am working on a application which is nicely modularized using requirejs. One of the modules called data service is in charge of providing other modules with data. Pretty much all get* methods of this module return javascript script objects in the the following format:

```
    res = {
    totalRows: 537,
    pageSize: 10,
    page: 15,
    rows: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Angelina'
            ...
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Halle'
            ...
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Scarlet'
            ...
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            name: 'Rihanna'
            ...
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            name: 'Shakira'
            ...
        },
                ....
       //10 rows
        {
            id: 10,
            name: 'Kate'
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to initialize the data table by providing it with rows for the current page, current page number, page size and the total number of records or pages so that it "knows" which page is currently being displayed as well as the number of available pages. Which in turn would allow the DT to build the pager correctly allowing the user to navigate to other pages in which case we would make another call to data service module to retrieve data from the database for the selected page.

Comment: like this? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17065148/how-to-select-second-page-as-initial-page-with-jquery-datatable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17065148/how-to-select-second-page-as-initial-page-with-jquery-datatable)

Comment: Not exactly. Please have a look at this example: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html. They specify the URL where to get the data when paging, sorting, filtering etc. In the project I am working on, I can not do that. We have a specific JS module that deals with retrieving data and whose get* methods return JavaScript objects as indicated in the questions above.