# Bootstrap/DataTable - How to set default page

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I am working with https://datatables.net and Bootstrap.

This is my code for displaying the Data Table:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document)
        .ready(function () {
            $('#datatable').dataTable({
                "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
                "page": 10
            });
        });
</script>
```

I have no problems to make the table run without problems. However i want to change the default page not to be the first one as by default.

I have tried to set the default page to be number 10. I mean when the table is loaded not to show page number 1, but for instance to show as active page number 10.

However it seems i can not do that. Can you please help me out ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **[`fnPageChange`](https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnPageChange)** `function` provided by `DataTables API` and use that on object of `datatables` and change it dynamically on page load as below:

```
$(document)
  .ready(function() {
    var table = $('#datatable').dataTable({
      "order": [
        [0, "desc"]
      ],
      "page": 10
    });
    //store reference in a variable say table here
    table.fnPageChange(2,true); //change page to 2 and redraw the table
});
```

Where `2` is the page number and the second parameter asks `datatable` to `redraw`.

**[`FIDDLE DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/UvjnT/674/)**

**Note: - If you are using `dataTables` version 1.10 or above you can use below option**

There is a **[`displayStart`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/displayStart)** option that will allow you to set the default page.

Do note that the `displayStart` value is a zero based count of records, not pages. If you have 10 records per page, `displayStart: 10` will show page `2`

```
$('#my-datatable').DataTable( {
  'displayStart': 10
} );
```

**[`Source`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24833857/2065039)**

Answer (score 4):

you could use a callback initComplete:

```
$('#datatable').dataTable({    
   initComplete: function () {                    
                    this.api().page(2).draw( 'page' );
                }
});
```

[documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page())

Answer (score 1):

When ever the page load just trigger below class

```
$( ".paginate_button  [data-dt-idx='10']" ).trigger("click");
```

I tried at my end it works for me. We can do the same with different selectors also